# Multiple python scripts subprocess at the same time problem

Tags: python, cron, subprocess, python-multiprocessing

I have this flow on python scripts:

```
1. script1 ARG1 (while true) running in loop:

 - subprocess.Popen ffmpeg (while true)
 - processing audio file
 - some if, mysql etc things
 - after run the script result a variable1
 - subprocess.Popen to script2 with variable1 as parameter

2. script2: (one time execution at 5 seconds trigger by script1)
 - some things to do in mysql, if, etc (2 seconds duration)
 - p1 = subprocess.Popen to script3 (3-7 seconds duration)
 - p2 = subprocess.Popen to script4 (3-7 seconds duration)
 - p1.wait()
 - p2.wait()

3. script3: (one time execution when trigger by script2)
 - some things to do in mysql, if, etc (3-7 seconds duration)

4. script4: (one time execution when trigger by script2)
 - some things to do in mysql, if, etc (3-7 seconds duration)
 - subprocess.Popen ffmpeg (<1sec duration)

5. script5: (while true) loop
 - check the mysql at every second and take some decisions
 - - subprocess.Popen ffmpeg (<1sec duration)

5. script6: (while true) loop
 - check the mysql at every second and take some decisions
 - subprocess.Popen ffmpeg (<1sec duration)
```

now the problem:
 - if i run script1, script5, script6 from shell all is working perfectly
 - if i put them to crontab all is working perfectly

BUT if i run them from a python script with:

```
subprocess.Popen(script1)
subprocess.Popen(script5)
subprocess.Popen(script6)
```

**after some time (5-15minutes) some of them stops until all of them die**

I need to run those three main scripts for each ARG from a database (5-6 args) and I don't want to add to crontab 18 lines.
I think my big problem is that I didn't realize how to export the logs from subprocess maybe there i have some errors when i run them with subprocess.

I need an opinion, what you think guys, i need to redesign my scripts in an single one and declare each script as function/import and open them with multiprocessing.process or exist a solution to run them in background as is ?

Comment: It's hard to debug your specific problem because you need to provide more detail on how exactly they stop, whether there is any output, exit codes etc. But from a wider perspective, yes I think you need to redisign your scripts - your design sounds very unwieldy and you can probably achieve everything you need by integrating them into one or two scripts. it's hard to say more without knowing more details about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yea the design is unwieldy but i don't think the problem comes from the main scripts, rather from the general script that do only the start of those. For me is sounds like the general script reaches a certain limit of memory of stdout or stderr and close, maybe. I will study more the docs of subprocess.